# Putting methods in a class in views.py

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple todo app just to learn Python & Django. My current code:

```
def create_task(request):
    # code for creating a task

def delete_task(request, task_id):
    # code for deleting task

def show(request, task_id):
    # show a task

def list(request):
    # show list of tasks

def create_sub_task(request):
    # code for creating a sub_task

def delete_sub_task(request, sub_task_id):
    # code for deleting sub_task

def flip_sub_task_completed(request, sub_task_id)
    # make a sub_task completed/uncompleted
```

As you can see, a task has subtasks. This is working fine. But I think it would be better to separate Tasks and SubTasks, and create 2 classes for them. Would it be better? And how would I go on achieving that? How would I need to change my `urlpatterns = [` to make it work? Thanks a lot!

edit:
models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SubTask(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You should post your `urls.py` and also your `models.py`. Anyhow, a task could simply have an FK to `self` and those with FK is a subtask.

Comment: @HigorRossato added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably *not* better to create a separate model for SubTasks – instead add a `parent` foreign key to your `Task` model; tasks with parents are subtasks:

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    # ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='subtasks')
```

If you need a multi-level hierarchy, I suggest looking into Django-Treebeard or Django-MPTT, which can be used for efficient modeling of trees in Django models.

Comment: I just wanna structure code a little better, and not have lots of methods in one file. I come from PHP background

Comment: @Tomas by doing what AKX suggested you'd eliminate the 3 last functions of yours because you'd deal with a single table and it's a bit more logical. I mean, a subtask is still a task with a parent

Comment: @HigorRossato Let's say I don't want a Task to have `completed` field, but I want that for a SubTask + other functionalities specific for a subtask.

Comment: Then you might want to look into Django's model inheritance (which is superpowered by https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and even so, you could use class-based views (CBVs) to DRY your code out.